# UISplitViewControllerDelegate/UIPopoverDelegate methods not called on right-to-left swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` subclass that implements both `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` and `UIPopoverController` delegate hooks to be notified when the master pane popover is being presented or dismissed via:

1. `splitViewController:popoverController:willPresentViewController:`
2. `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:`

This split view controller has `presentsWithGesture` set to `YES`.

When 1. is called, I make sure to set the delegate for the popover (second argument in the method call) to `self`.

What works:

- With the master pane visible, when I tap outside the master pane, the *should dismiss* hook gets called
- With the master pane hidden, when I tap the navbar button to reveal the master pane, the *will show* hook gets called
- With the master pane hidden, when I swipe from left to right to reveal the master pane, the *will show* hook gets called

What doesn't work:

- With the master pane visible, when I swipe from right to left to hide the master pane, no delegate hooks are called

I'm pretty sure all delegates are correctly set.

In the debugger, I grabbed the memory ref for the popover controller (which is always the same) and after swiping right-to-left, I confirm its delegate is still correctly set — the methods just aren't being called.

Anything wrong with the setup or is this a UIKit bug/oversight?

Comment: Are you sure this is a supported gesture? I am only aware of left to right to open the popover.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Did you ever make progress with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging I found there is a difference between tapping outside (a dismiss) and swiping away (a hide.) This is what you need, and what I've now used to detect the "swipe away":

[UISplitViewControllerDelegate splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/splitViewController%3awillHideViewController%3awithBarButtonItem%3aforPopoverController%3a)